# Cutting off particular part of texts

Tags: python, pandas

I have email text data in my DataFrame. And I see some email contains their signature in it saying their department in their companies such as below

```
==================================
ABCD corporation
 IT department
 Name
 Email
==================================
```

In order to proceed to data analysis, I dont need these signature part so I kinda of want to get rid of them. 
I have made a list of these separation such as "===" and "----" that people use for their signature.
So I kinda wanna write a code that cuts all the texts in it if "==" appears more than 4 times or something.
Is there any pythonic way to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

```
stri="""
jshsb sjhsvs jwjj bla bla bla
==================================
ABCD corporation
 IT department
 Name
 Email
==================================
"""

stri=stri.split()
for i in range(len(stri)):
    if ('====' in stri[i]) or ('----' in stri[i]):
        stri=stri[:i]
        break

print(' '.join(stri))
```

Output:

```
jshsb sjhsvs jwjj bla bla bla
```

Comment: That works perfectly as I wanted! But how do you apply it to all rows in series?
As I tried, it combined all rows as one text and get rid of everything after "==" appeared with for sentence. Or it simply says series doesnt have split()..

Comment: What do you mean, rows in series? In this code, the text is broken down to words, or better to blocks of characters that do not contain whitespace. If you mean that you prefer to break down the text into lines instead of "words" you can use the splitlines() instead of split()